# Orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation

is there any difference when we use following two methods for orientation change in iOS.

1) Using NotificationCenter

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChange) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

-(void) orientationChange
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    NSLog(@"Orientation =%d",orientation);
    NSLog(@"in Testtt");
}
```

2) ViewController Orientation delegate methods

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight == interfaceOrientation || UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == interfaceOrientation)
        return YES;
    else 
        return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case you will receive UIDeviceOrientation.`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` returns **UIDeviceOrientation**, device orientation. But note that UIDeviceOrientation  is not always UIInterfaceOrientation. For example, when your device is on a plain table you can receive unexpected value (`UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`).

In `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method you can access UIInterfaceOrientation, current orientation of the interface.